VBA Word. Изменение ширины столбца таблицы с объединенными ячейками
Как через VBA изменять ширину столбца в таблице с объединенными ячейками? Вручную делается так:

ухватить мышой за правую границу таблицы;
растянуть на ширину 17 см
ухватить мышой за центральную "ось"
растянуть правую часть на ширину 9 см.



В общем, это целый геморрой. Если представить, что это первая таблица в документе и в ней три строки, то:
Option Explicit

Sub Macro2()
  Dim i&, w#
  With ThisDocument.Tables(1)
    .Cell(1, 4).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=50, RulerStyle:=wdAdjustFirstColumn
    For i = 1 To 4: w = w + .Cell(1, i).Width: Next
    .Cell(2, 1).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=w, RulerStyle:=wdAdjustFirstColumn
    .Cell(3, 1).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=w, RulerStyle:=wdAdjustFirstColumn
  End With
End Sub


Вы можете отметить мой ответ как принятый, если он помог.

Ну що там, Сашко?
